# AWS EC2 SSH connection drops and reconnect attempts time-out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

This seems to be a huge issue that a lot of people are experiencing. I have yet to see a resolution.

I am using VSCode with the Remote-SSH extension to access my ec2 instance. It worked perfectly for about 4 years. Then about a year to a year and a half ago I started experiencing random dropped SSH connections to my instances. Any attempts to reconnect would time out.

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-?-?-?-?.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down

[13:41:44.906] Resolver error: Error: The operation timed out
```

Now what's weird with this is that the situation tends to correct itself. Sometimes it takes 10-15 minutes, sometimes a few hours, but rarely more than a day. Rebooting the instance sometimes works but not always. Attempts to connect through my AWS console are met with the following error even though status checks pass.

[image]

Any ideas? AWS support is not available because this is a basic support plan.

Comment: did you check the CPU consumption?

Comment: Yes, it never went above 50%